# How to append a string to every cell (with awk)?

Tags: awk, cal

This is an output of `cal`. What is the simplest way to append an additional `<SPACE>` to every cell?

```
     June 2021        
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
       1  2  3  4  5  
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12  
13 14 15 16 17 18 19  
20 21 22 23 24 25 26  
27 28 29 30
```

An expected result:

```
     June 2021
Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa
         1   2   3   4   5
 6   7   8   9  10  11  12
13  14  15  16  17  18  19
20  21  22  23  24  25  26
27  28  29  30
```

Comment: Please provide the expected result. It's unclear what you mean by "cell" here.

Comment: Do you **really** want a blank char stuck on the end of every line? Do you **really**  want `June<blank>2021` to become `June<blank><blank>2021`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ cal | awk '{ gsub(/[^ ] |   /, "& ") }1'
```

or using `sed`:

```
$ cal | sed -E 's/[^ ] |   /& /g'
      June  2021
Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa
         1   2   3   4   5
 6   7   8   9  10  11  12
13  14  15  16  17  18  19
20  21  22  23  24  25  26
27  28  29  30
```

Answer (score 6):

This may be what you're trying to do:

```
$ cal | awk 'NR>1{gsub(/.../,"& ")}1'
      June 2021
Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa
         1   2   3   4   5
 6   7   8   9  10  11  12
13  14  15  16  17  18  19
20  21  22  23  24  25  26
27  28  29  30
```

Note that it won't add a blank to the "cell" at the end of each line, nor will it add an extra blank after the "cell"s on the month+year line.

Comment: `/.../` is any three chars?

Comment: Correct. I could alternatively have used `.{3}` but that's 1 extra char of typing :-) and it wouldn't work in an awk version that doesn't support regexp intervals, e.g. either `nawk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` on Solaris, I can't remember which, and older versions of GNU awk without `--re-intervals`.

Answer (score 1):

GNU awk

```bsh
cal | cat | gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS="3 3 3 3 3 3 2" 'NR > 1 {$1 = $1} 1'
```

Comment: Frustrating that the program does not agree with its own man page: "-h. Turns off highlighting of today."

Comment: Does the `| cat` really do anything? When I run `cal` I see today highlighted but when I pipe it to anything the highlighting is gone so I think `cal` is managing that itself and since you're piping to `gawk` you don't need another `| cat` in between.